# How do I navigate to a react native screen which displays like iOS's 'fullScreen' mode

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to navigate to another screen in my react native app which presents itself like iOS presents it's view in 'fullScreen' mode. I have attached the example, is it possible to do it in React-Navigation?

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.3",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.3",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.6",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.3",
```

[image]

Comment: you want to delete the bar of 'Accont' and 'Done'  ?

Comment: @krimo no, I want to display it as a modal. This feature is available in iOS. You notice the view is not exactly covered entirely by the screen? The top can be dragged down and you will be taken to the previous view. That is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Sory I don't know how to do it

Comment: Try this from react-navigation Docs : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in the screen options where you defined the navigation.
`cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forModalPresentationIOS`